# Magento 2 stores with different product url

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

Here is my situation, my company buy product with no brand and sell them in its own brand.

We have 2 websites and 2 brands, some products exist in both of our brand with different name.

Example : product A of brand A named BrandA Product Premium and the same product on the other site is named BrandB Product Super.

But on both website the url-key is the same (the name of the product in the default view) so on site1 I have :

http://www.site1.com/brand-a-product-premium.html that is very good.

On site2 I have http://www.site2.com/brand-a-product-premium.html If you type in the correct url : http://www.site2.com/brand-b-product-super.html you are redirected to the bad url.

I can correct this by creating a custom url_rewrite, but there are thousands of product in this case, so I may have done something wrong and there should be a better solution for this.

May I have some help ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one instance of Magento in a multistore setup you can override the url key as well as any other product attribute for each store view. Select the store view for site 2 from the dropdown on the left hand side of the edit product page and then override the required fields for that store view.

I have a multistore site where I sell some products on both but not all and using the above method gives me full control over every aspect of the same product for each store view. e.g. Custom name, description, images, categories etc. To ensure that a product is not shown on a particular site via catalog or search, I disable that product in that store view by setting visibility to none.

Do not use the URL rewrite option this will come back to haunt you!

Comment: Hi,in my product in the backend, I have configure a different url in each store view, but on the frontend it's always the default one that is used. So not the good one on the second site. (the first use the same as default even if "use default" option is unchecked)